# SQLite Database Browser - problem with importing national fonts

Tags: android, database, sqlite, csv, import

I'm using SQLite database in my android project. I want to store there lots of string containing polish fonts. To manage the database I'm using SQLite Database Browser. The problem is: when I'm importing csv filled with strings to database, my text gets changed from, for example "Wysyłaj własnoręcznie" to "Wysy³aj w³asnorêcznie". Any ideas how to properly convert this kind of characters?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for your problem?
 i am having same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are opening an InputStream to some source for the csv text, then wrapping that in an InputStreamReader. You need to specify the proper encoding when creating the InputStreamReader. The default encoding is probably ISO-8869-1 and your text is probably UTF-8. This would explain why characters beyond U_007F are not interpreted correctly.

Comment: @Amourreux - When you create an `InputStreamReader` from an `InputStream`, there's an optional second argument to specify the character encoding. For example: `InputStreamReader rdr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");`.